# Infinite sums in python

Tags: python

I have heard that python can do infinite sums. For instance if I want to evaluate the infinite sum:

```
1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - 1/11 + ...
```

How should I go about? I am a newbie to python. So I would appreciate if someone could write out the entire code and if I need to include/import something.

For instance, in wolfram alpha if I input `Summation (-1)^(n-1)/(2*n-1) from n=1 to infinity` it gives the answer as `0.785395`. I want the answer computed to a desired accuracy say, as in the case of wolfram alpha upto 6 digits.

Further, I was looking at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552213/which-programming-language-or-a-library-can-process-infinite-series) and tried to mimic that but it gives me the following errors:

```
`NameError: name 'Infinity' is not defined`
`NameError: name 'Inf' is not defined`
```

Thanks,
Adhvaitha

Comment: Are you expecting that you will be able to compute the limit of an infinite series? Which will often be an irrational number? Or do you want an approximation with a certain level of precision?

Comment: This is a job for mathematicans or perhaps scientific software, not for a general-purpose programming language.

Comment: @Adhvaitha That's only works on Cray supercomputer, but this beast can execute _any_ endless loop in 7-8 seconds!

Comment: For instance, in wolfram alpha if I input "Summation (-1)^(n-1)/(2*n-1) from n=1 to infinity" it gives the answer as 0.785395. I want the answer computed to a desired accuracy say, as in the case of wolfram alpha upto 6 digits. And the downvoter, could you kindly provide the reason for the downvote.

Comment: "...python can do infinite sums" it cannot iterate infinite times, only finite times, so your sums cannot have infinite precision. But python is powerful with simple, readable code. BTW, you seem a matlab user and you may be interested in numpy, scipy and sagemath, mathematics modules for python.

Comment: I was looking at this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552213/which-programming-language-or-a-library-can-process-infinite-series) and tried to mimic that but it gives me the following error "NameError: name 'Infinity' is not defined"

Comment: @Adhvaitha , the downvoter (and me) thought you were a teen asking for the impossible :-) Please post your Summation thingy to your post before you get more downvotes.

Comment: @Adhvaitha I'm not a downvoter but I'd hazard a guess at the reason: your question, on first glance, seems to be a [show me the codes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59944/allow-users-to-filter-out-questions-based-on-keywords-like-plz-and-codes) type question, which some people automatically downvote.

Comment: Python isn't any CAS - you have to tell it what the literal "Infinity" or "Inf" mean.

Comment: You have to use Sympy, a symbolic language addition for python. The answer to your question is detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552213/which-programming-language-or-a-library-can-process-infinite-series/37122445#37122445

Answer (score 8):

While it still is finite, you can approximate that series using the [`fractions`](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) and [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) modules:

```
from fractions import Fraction
from decimal import Decimal

repetitions = 100

d = 1
r = Fraction(1, d)

for n in range(repetitions):
    r += Fraction(1, d) - Fraction(1, d + 2)
    d += 4

print(Decimal(r.numerator)/Decimal(r.denominator))
```

I think this comes closest to what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about `fractions`, and for removing the comment from my answer.. :-)

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: Yeah, it was overly aggresive and not thought through - I didn't even read the second part of your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Python has unlimited precision integers, but not unlimited precision floats.  There are packages you can use that provide that, though.

And nothing can "complete" an infinite sum, since it involves an infinite number of steps.  You'll need to find a closed form for the sum, and then evaluate that, or accept an approximation achieved by terminating the infinite sum when a precision criterion is met.

Comment: For "unlimited" precision floats, use the [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) python module. Batteries included! :)

Answer (score 5):

A bit of a shot in the dark here... I bet when you heard about Python being able to do infinite sums, what they meant was that in Python [long integers have unlimited precision](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex).

Clearly, this has nothing to do with summing infinite series.

I am not aware of any facet of Python that would make it particularly well suited to computing this kind of sums (or indeed establishing whether a sum is convergent).

You could try the direct summation of terms, with some reasonable stopping criterion. However, this will only work for well-behaved series.

Finally, just to give you some flavour of the complexity of what you're asking for, [academic papers get published](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1997-66-220/S0025-5718-97-00869-7/S0025-5718-97-00869-7.pdf) whose sole purpose is to deal with the summation of certain small classes of series. The general problem that you're posing isn't as easy as it may seem.

Answer (score 4):

```
#It may be late answer but the following works well.

repetitions = 50

r = 0.0

for i in range(repetitions):
   ii=i+1 # because in python index start from 0
   r+=((-1)**(ii-1))/(2*ii-1.0)

print r

#the output is r=0.780398663148, you can increase the repetitions for more accuracy
```

Answer (score 3):

For some series, such as the one shown, you can use the [**alternating series test**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test) to compute the sum to within a desired error.  Libraries such as [**Decimal**](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html), [**GyPy**](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GmPy), [**mpmath**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test), or [**bigfloat**](http://packages.python.org/bigfloat/), etc, can be used if your calculation will bump into the precision of built-in floats.

**Note on integer approaches**:
 Although the ratio-of-integers approachs seems more accurate, they are completely impractical for real calculations.  The reason for this is: 1) adding fractions requires creating equal denominators, and this basically requires multiplying the denominators, so by then end, the size of the numbers is something like `n!` (i.e., the [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test)); and, 2) for the example series, a precision of `m` digits requires `m` terms.  Therefore, even for only six digit accuracy, one requires numbers roughly equal to 1000000! = **8×10<sup>5,565,708</sup>**.  For bigger numbers, it's roughly 10<sup>10<sup>n</sup></sup>, which quickly becomes completely impractical.  Meanwhile, a decimal solution calculated to 6 or 7 or even 40 digits is trivial.

For example, running nightcrackers solution, the times and numbers of digits in the denominator or numerator I get are:

```
    n      t       n_digits_in_denominator
   10      0.0003  14
  100      0.0167  170
 1000      5.5027  1727
10000      ????    ????   (gave up after waiting one hour)
```

And this becomes impractical for only ~4 digits of accuracy.

So if you want to exactly calculate a finite and small number of terms and express the final result as a ratio, then the integer solutions would be a good choice, but if you want to express the final result as a decimal, you'd be better off just sticking with decimals.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using sympy like that:

```py
from sympy import oo, Sum
from sympy.abc import n
inf_sum = Sum((-1)**n/(2*n + 1), (n, 0, oo))    # n goes from 0 to infinity
print(inf_sum.doit())
```

This will give you `pi/4` that is the same that you got from Wolfram Alpha.